# Loading a GLTF file (as SVF2, ie. after upload to ACC) in a aggregated viewer has wrong orientation, breaks world-up vector

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

After uploading a GLTF file to ACC and then loading it in a aggregated viewer with an existing Revit model the orientation of the models is wrong (ZY axis mismatch). Instead the world up vector is changed.

Any pointers on how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a good solution using `setPlacementTransform`

```js
const swapYZ = new THREE.Matrix4().set(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)

export function fixGltfOrientation(model: Model) {
  const node = model.getDocumentNode()
  const name = node?.getRootNode()?.children[0]?.name()

  if (name?.endsWith(".glb")) {
    model.setPlacementTransform(swapYZ)
  }
}
```